# How to print out whole string of private value of object when debug flutter

Tags: debugging, flutter

I'm debugging code which using [`LocalStorage`](https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage).

Found that it's hard to view the whole value of `_file.path`:

- print `this._file.path` will give error `error: org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:6: Error: The getter 'file' isn't defined for the class 'LocalStorage'`
- `WATCH` window expand this value, but only see part of the string
- print `this` and expand to this value, only see part of the string value `---/Application/3...` ended with `...` too.

I can change the lib's code to add a new line `print(_file.path);` but **I don't think it's recommendatory since it change the lib's source code**.

[image: LocalStorage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to **Debug** Side Window
2. Open Variables
3. Right Click and Copy value
4. Open new empty editor
5. Right Click on editor and Paste

Here is working example that I tried just now

[longString with 'end' characters at the end of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FItVS.gif)

In summary, even getting values by using **print(_longString)** command will only display up to 1023 characters. But, using copy value, I got all of existed 1400 characters.

You can try longer characters if you want

Comment: The value of `private property` can't `print` in `debug console`(Error: The getter '_value' isn't defined for the class 'YourClass'.).  In you demo, it's a `local variable` which can `print`.

Comment: unfortunately I just encountered same issues when working on Classes. this is the demo https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_debug_long_string/raw/master/demo.gif 

this is the repo https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_debug_long_string

Comment: ah, I see, sounds not I didn't test the long enough string.

Answer (score 0):

https://xxx.yyy.com:0909/api/balance{
  "Cash": 156.65,
  "MyCash": 0.0,
  "CartDate": "2019-07-15T11:01:20.8314598+08:00",
  "isEnabled": false
}

To get above response in my LOG i used below

```
final responseData =responseData = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
debugPrint(
    '$_tagResponse ${responseData.statusCode} - ${url + responseData.body}');
```

Comment: I don't think it's recommendatory to add `debugPrint` in lib's code since it change the lib's source code.

Comment: any link to refer it?

Comment: no, but every time I edit a source file from outside of project in vscode, it will warning me.    And the point of my question is the `Watch` can see the `_file.path`, just not show the full string value,  my question would be how to view the whole string value without need to modify the source file from outside of project. I don't want to change the code in pub `.pub-cache`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dragging the Watch window to the right until the entire value is visible?

Another option is to use Android Studio instead which always gives a 'View' link when the value doesn't fit inline, which opens a popup displaying the entire value.

Comment: if the string too long, it will not display all in vscode. it ended like `aaa...`